# Invocable Class can't run call to API method

Tags: apex, api, process-builder

I have a process builder executing the following Apex class when the criteria is met. Everything runs nicely until the last line, where the API method is called and a map is passed.

```
public class Cls_Location {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Device Id')
    public static void getCoordinates(List<Id> dList) {

        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        for(Id i : dList) {
            ids.add(i);
            system.debug(i);
        }

        //sensor coordinates map and respective list
        Map<Id, List<Double>> sCoord = new Map<Id, List<Double>>();
        List<Double> sCoordList = new List<Double>();
        //device coordinates map and respective list
        Map<Id, List<Double>> dCoord = new Map<Id, List<Double>>();
        List<Double> dCoordList = new List<Double>();

        for(Device__c qDevice : [SELECT Id, Name, 
                                   Geo_Ip_Location__c, Geo_Ip_Location__Latitude__s, Geo_Ip_Location__Longitude__s
                                    FROM Device__c
                                    WHERE Id IN :ids]) {



                                        system.debug('Query: ' + qDevice);        
                                    Double dLat  = qDevice.Geo_Ip_Location__Latitude__s;
                                    Double dLgtd = qDevice.Geo_Ip_Location__Longitude__s;
                                        system.debug('dLat: ' + dLat);
                                        system.debug('dLgtd: ' + dLgtd);

                                    dCoordList.add(dLat);
                                    dCoordList.add(dLgtd);
                                    dCoord.put(qDevice.Id, dCoordList);
                                        system.debug('dCoord: ' + dCoord);
                                         } 


        if (dCoord.size() > 0) {

        for (Id c : dCoord.keySet()) {
            system.debug('Device Lat: ' + dCoord.get(c)[0]);
            system.debug('Device Longtd: '+ dCoord.get(c)[1]);
        }

        Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService.runCallout(dCoord);

        } 
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet of the API callout class and method:

```
public class Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService {

public static HttpResponse runCallout(Map<Id, List<Double>> m1) {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(MAPS_URL);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);



            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {

//JSON PARSING is done here
```

Is there any way around this?

Grateful for your time.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions thrown in the debug log when you execute this callout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the error you would get in  your debug logs is 
**Uncommited Work Pending:**.

There is a limitation in SF, if you do a dml, you cannot do a callout in same transaction. This is just the way SF works.

So if your process builder is running, that means you already did a DML. Now from Process Builder you calling an Invocable method, which does callout.

Thus it will fail. Is there a workaround for this?

ofc. You have to use future method.

```
public class Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService  {

@future(callout=true)

public static void runCallout(String input) {
        Map<Id, List<Double>> m1 =(Map<Id, List<Double>>) JSON.deserialize(input, Map<Id, List<Double>>.class);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        //request.setEndpoint(MAPS_URL);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
}
}
```

Calling from your invocable method like

```
 Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService.runCallout(JSON.serialize(dCoord));
```

As future method can only accept primitive datatype, I have to convert your Map of `(Map<Id, List<Double>>)` to JSON string and then deserialize and use it.

Edit : If you want to use queuable Apex then Main class will be

```
public class Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService  implements  Queueable,Database.AllowsCallout{

    private Map<Id, List<Double>> m1;


    public Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService(Map<Id, List<Double>> m1){
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(MAPS_URL);
            request.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    }
¬}
```

And then you would call your queuable like :

```
 System.enqueueJob(new Cls_GoogleMapsCalloutService  (dCoord));
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

Source: http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2015/03/invoking-apex-callout-from-process.html

Comment: could also use queueable and avoid the serialization/deserialization of the map

Comment: Yups, I prefer Queuable....  cause of chaining feature.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, that helps a lot! I just got home but I'll try this tomorrow at work. **[Is this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_queueable)**  the queuable you're referring to? I'm just starting as a developer, grateful for the patience :)

Comment: Good Morning, @PranayJaiswal . I'm curious how can I use the queuable interface to substitute the JSON serialize/deserialize. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: @RuiTorres edited answer to represent it